# Can I infinitely loop a pyautogui function using time.sleep()?

Tags: python, time, pyautogui

I'm very new to python and I'm just trying to create a simple mouse moving+clicking script to remove some of my sent LinkedIn connection requests. I'm trying to make it loop infinitely but I just can't figure it out :(

```
import pyautogui
from time import sleep

time.sleep(2)

pyautogui.PAUSE = 2.5

pyautogui.moveTo(1171, 458)
pyautogui.click()
pyautogui.moveTo(1123, 403)
pyautogui.click()
```

I tried to do the following, but it doesn't execute the code at all and I need to stop the kernel:

```
import pyautogui
from time import sleep

while True:
    sleep(2)

pyautogui.PAUSE = 2.5

pyautogui.moveTo(1171, 458)
pyautogui.click()
pyautogui.moveTo(1123, 403)
pyautogui.click()
```

Comment: The only thing being repeated by that loop is the `sleep(2)`.  If you want the `pyautogui` calls to be repeated as well, they need to be indented to the same level as the `sleep`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a `while` loop like this:

```
from time import sleep
import pyautogui

pyautogui.PAUSE = 2.5

while True:
    sleep(2)

    pyautogui.moveTo(1171, 458)
    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.moveTo(1123, 403)
    pyautogui.click()
```

If you don't want the script to sleep for 2 seconds every time, you can move the `sleep(2)` above the `while True:` and remove the spaces behind the `sleep(2)`